# Overlay image with HTML widget

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML code for a widget that I am wanting to overlay onto an image in my blog.  I am unsure what the HTML code would be to accomplish this.  Suggestions?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely position your widget over the top of the image and put both of them inside a container but it's hard to know without seeing what exactly you want to do with your widget.

Here is a very crude example with an image and some text.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.img-1 {
  width: 300px;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/941736/pexels-photo-941736.jpeg" class="img-1">
<div class="overlay">
Div content to go over the top of the image.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: an example of what I am trying to accomplish can be seen at the top of this website: https://www.bookmundi.com/travel-insurance I have the code for the widget but wanted to replicate this (with my own image of course).